# SvelteKit stores don't match client-side and server-side

Tags: javascript, svelte, server-side-rendering, store, sveltekit

In SvelteKit, it seems that stores do not sync between the client-side and server-side. In other words, if one modifies a store on the client-side, when it is retrieved on the server-side, it will not be modified, and vice versa.

You can see this behaviour in the minimal reproducible example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-fpp2y8?file=src/routes/+page.svelte

**My question is: What is the idiomatic, or normal way to modify a server-side store when on the client-side?**

To avoid the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), what I am trying to do specifically is the following:

The user of an EPOS system has a 'currentSale' store, which is loaded on accessing the `/epos` route on the server-side, specifically so that [Prisma](https://prisma.io) can get more information about the products, customer attached etc.

However, the problem arises when, for example, the user tries to increment the quantity of a product in the EPOS sale. Trying to update the store does not work, as it doesn't save server-side. And using a whole API route, or [form action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement) seems overkill and not optimized/optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try to use stores on the server in the first place; they are not meant for that.

> And using a whole API route, or form action seems overkill and not optimized/optimal.

That is exactly what you should be using when you want to modify data on the server. I am not a fan of API routes as they are quite limited and verbose, but form actions are quite versatile as multiple named actions can exist for the same page.

Comment: I see; How should I store this data then? It needs to be loaded server-side due to `Prisma` only allowing server-side access, but at the same time, it needs to be editable client-side for quick and responsive modification - I was thinking of `localStorage` but that has a similar pitfall in being client-side specific. Is there some Svelte/SvelteKit feature I'm forgetting about, or how should I go about this?

Comment: Stores have very specific purposes, most of the time you do not need them at all. All state within a component is reactive by default. Data from the server should be provided by a [`load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load), if it has to execute on the server, put it in `+page.server.js`/`ts`. If you change something via a form action, the data is invalidated automatically and reloaded if you use [`enhance`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance).